# Find Ranges of Null Values in a Column - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the ranges of NaN values in a df like this:

```
    [Column_1]     [Column_2]
1       A             10
2       B             20
3       C             NaN
4       D             NaN
5       E             NaN
6       F             60
7       G             65
8       H             NaN
9       I             NaN
10      J             NaN
11      K             90
12      L             NaN
13      M             100
```

So, for now what I just did was to list the index of the NaN values with this line:

```
df['Column_2'].isnull()].index.tolist()
```

But then, I don't know how to set the intervals of these values in terms of Column_1, which for this case would be:

```
 [C-E] [H-J] [L]
```

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the rows where the values in `Column_2` are `NaN`, then `groupby` these rows on consecutive occurrence of `NaN` values in `Column_2` and collect the corresponding values of `Column_1` inside a list comprehension:

```
m = df['Column_2'].isna()
r = [[*g['Column_1']] for _, g in df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())]
```

---

```
print(r)
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['L']]
```

Comment: Thanks! @Shubham_Sharma, I just added a few lines to get the answer I wanted.
May I ask you for a quick explanation of the structure of your code? I am not familiar with some syntax you did.

Comment: Particulary: *g,  for _,  ~m,  .cumsum()

Comment: `(~m).cumsum` is used to create a grouper which can be used to group the dataframe on discrete consecutive occurrences of `NaN` values in column 2. `[*g[column1]]` is used to unpack the values in `column1` in grouped frame `g` essentially it is equivalent to using `g[column1].tolist()`